# Triggering event from Class A to Class B using interface in Java

Tags: java, interface, listener

Suppose I have defined a class with interface like this:

```
public class myClass {

    public void test() {
        //here I want to trigger `onStartListener`
    }

    interface OnStartListener {
        public void onStart();
    }
}
```

and class B I have defined like this:

```
public class ClassB implements myClass.OnStartListener {
    public void ClassB() {
        myClass test1 = new myClass();
        myClass.test();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("start triggered");
    }
}
```

How can I trigger `OnStartListener` from `test` method of `myClass` so `ClassB` can handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to subscribe your listener and call the method in the class A:

```
public class ClassB implements myClass.OnStartListener {
    public void ClassB() {
        myClass test1 = new myClass(this);
        //test1.setListener(this);
        myClass.test();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("start triggered");
    }
}
```

and

```
    public class myClass {
    OnStartListener myListener;

    public myClass(OnStartListener myListener) {
             this.myListener = myListener;
        }
    public void test() {
            //here I want to trigger `onStartListener`
            myListener.onStart();
    }

        interface OnStartListener {
            public void onStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: how? I want to trigger from `myClass` and ClassB has already subscribed to listen to that event.

Comment: Is it possible that instead of using `setListener`, I directly use `this` in constructor to instantiate the `OnStartListener`? For eg. like this: this.myListener = (OnStartListener) this;

Comment: I have seen your updated answer... But I actually meant is. I am initializing `myClass` already in `ClassB` like this... `new myClass()`. Instead of passing reference inside it, if I directly use `this` inside myClass constructor: `this.myListener = (OnStartListener) this`, will this work? Because I think it's already having a reference to the initiator.

Comment: this.myListener = this is not going to work because the myClass is receiving an interface but my Class doest not implements that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how frameworks like swing handle listeners. Basically you need to "register" the listener instance (`ClassB` instance) with `myClass` and call `onStart()` on it.

`ClassB` would probably contain a `List<OnStartListener>` which is used in a loop and `onStart()` is called on each element. Registering would mean assing the instance of `ClassB` to that list.